# Подключение к MySQL в режиме отсутствия проверки пароля, и изменение пароля пользователя root

Tags: mysql

Каким образом подключиться к БД MySQL в режиме без проверки пароля и изменить утраченный пароль на новый?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для изменения пароля у суперпользователя root необходимо подключиться к серверу MySQL в режиме отсутствия проверки пароля, изменить пароль, запустить сервер в обычном режиме, подключиться с использованием нового пароля.
Для этого необходимо выполнить всего несколько шагов:

1. Останавливаем mysql
    для этого в командной строке выполняем команду: 
   `net stop mysql`
   После остановки сервера консольное окно находится "в режиме ожидания", не закрывая это окно открываем новое;
2. Переходим в каталог куда была установлена MySQL используя команду: cd c:\<путь к папке bin> После того как текущая позиция в консоле будет указывать на папку bin. Выполняем команду:     
   `mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=root &`
   В результате выполнения команды сервер запустился в режиме в котором можно подключиться к нему без использования пароля
3. Запускаем клиент mysql:
   `mysql -u root`
4. Выполняем sql запрос:         
   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';`
   где newpwd - новый пароль
5. Применяем изменения: 
   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
   Далее изменения сохранены и у пользователя root - новый пароль. Для входа в MySQL в стандартном режиме необходимо запустить службу команда:            `net start mysql` Однако может возникнуть ошибка запуска службы в этом случае перезагружаем компьютер и конектимся к MySQL с новым паролем.